# Write a program that determines how many of each letter a name has

Tags: java

Here is the instructions/examples for the program that I have to do:

> Hello! Please enter your first name. Howdy
>
> Thank you. Now enter your last name. Doody
>
> Your first name is Howdy, and your last name is Doody.  WHAT A NICE
>   NAME YOU HAVE!!
>
> Your first name contains 5 letters, and your last name contains 5
>   letters.
>
> Your initials are: H D
>
> Your name contains:
>
> 3 d's
>
> 1 h
>
> 3 o's
>
> 1 w
>
> 2 y's
>
> Well, Howdy Doody, this has been fun. Good bye!

I can get all the way until the amount of letters in the name. My teacher said something about ASCII Character Set and that I only needed like 1 for loop. I do not know most of the array and other type stuff, and I want some help on how to make it into one loop. Here is my code so far:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoolSet2Problem4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello! Please enter your first name in all lower case:");
        String firstname = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println(); //this is just so it looks nice with another space
        System.out.println("Thank you. Now enter your last name in all lower case:");
        String lastname = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println(); //this is just so it looks nice with another space
        System.out.println("You first name is " + firstname + ", and your" + "\n" + "last name is " + lastname + ".");
        System.out.println("WHAT A NICE NAME YOU HAVE!!");
        System.out.println(); //this is just so it looks nice with another space
        int fnl = firstname.length();
        int lnl = lastname.length();
        System.out.println("Your first name countains " + fnl + " letters,");
        System.out.println("and your last name countains " + lnl + " letters.");
        System.out.println(); //this is just so it looks nice with another space
        char fni = firstname.charAt(0);
        char lni = lastname.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Your initials are: " + fni + " " + lni);
        System.out.println(); //this is just so it looks nice with another space

    int acount = 0; int bcount = 0; int ccount = 0; int dcount = 0; int ecount = 0; int fcount = 0; int gcount = 0; 
    int hcount = 0; int icount = 0; int jcount = 0; int kcount = 0; int lcount = 0; int mcount = 0; int ncount = 0;
    int ocount = 0; int pcount = 0; int qcount = 0; int rcount = 0; int scount = 0; int tcount = 0; int ucount = 0;
    int vcount = 0; int wcount = 0; int xcount = 0; int ycount = 0; int zcount = 0;

    for (int k = 0; ( (k < fnl) && (k < lnl) ); k++)
    {
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('a' | 'A')) acount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('a' | 'A')) acount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('b' | 'B')) bcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('b' | 'B')) ccount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('c' | 'C')) ccount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('c' | 'C')) dcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('d' | 'D')) dcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('d' | 'D')) dcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('e' | 'E')) ecount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('e' | 'E')) ecount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('f' | 'F')) fcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('f' | 'F')) fcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('g' | 'G')) gcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('g' | 'G')) gcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('h' | 'H')) hcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('h' | 'H')) hcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('i' | 'I')) icount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('i' | 'I')) icount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('j' | 'J')) jcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('j' | 'J')) jcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('k' | 'K')) kcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('k' | 'K')) kcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('l' | 'L')) lcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('l' | 'L')) lcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('m' | 'M')) mcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('m' | 'M')) mcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('n' | 'N')) ncount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('n' | 'N')) ncount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('o' | 'O')) ocount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('o' | 'O')) ocount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('p' | 'P')) pcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('p' | 'P')) pcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('q' | 'Q')) qcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('q' | 'Q')) qcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('r' | 'R')) rcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('r' | 'R')) rcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('s' | 'S')) scount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('s' | 'S')) scount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('t' | 'T')) tcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('t' | 'T')) tcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('u' | 'U')) ucount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('u' | 'U')) ucount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('v' | 'V')) vcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('v' | 'V')) vcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('w' | 'W')) wcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('w' | 'W')) wcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('x' | 'X')) xcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('x' | 'X')) xcount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('y' | 'Y')) ycount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('y' | 'Y')) ycount++;
        if (firstname.charAt(k) == ('z' | 'Z')) zcount++;
        if (lastname.charAt(k) == ('z' | 'Z')) zcount++;
    }
    System.out.println(); //this is just so it looks nice with another space
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + acount + " a\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + bcount + " b\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + ccount + " c\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + dcount + " d\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + ecount + " e\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + fcount + " f\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + gcount + " g\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + hcount + " h\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + icount + " i\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + jcount + " j\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + kcount + " k\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + lcount + " l\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + mcount + " m\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + ncount + " n\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + ocount + " o\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + pcount + " p\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + qcount + " q\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + rcount + " r\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + scount + " s\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + tcount + " t\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + ucount + " u\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + vcount + " v\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + wcount + " y\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + xcount + " x\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + ycount + " y\'s");
    System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " contains " + zcount + " z\'s");
}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated.

I know this is long but it is the only way I know how.

Comment: If you know how to (or allowed to) use a `map`, use that. It will make it much easier

Comment: I do not and therefore cannot use it.

Comment: Not familiar with concat and i tried equals which I know of and something went wrong, probably have to spend more time to look through it. Thanks though.

Comment: Okay. One solution is to concat the string (first + last) and iterate over the length of the new concatenated string. Also, use `equals()` to compare string instead of `==`. Also, your `if` condition is not correct. It should be something like `if (condtion1 == something || condition2 == something)...`

Comment: Again not completely familiar with concat and the || thing helped with the capital letters, I knew it just don't know why I wasn't putting it in.

Comment: 1) As you want a case-insensitive comparison, it's easiest to start by converting the user input into lower-case (`String lowerCaseLastname = lastname.toLowerCase();`) before doing the character-counting 2) Use an array for storing the counts of individual characters

Comment: Forget about ASCII. Java strings are counted sequences of Java char, which is a Unicode/UTF-16 code unit. If you want to make assumptions for simplicity, assume that each char is a complete character. You don't have to know which in order to group and count them. You might ask, too, if you really need to determine that the user typed in letters. I wouldn't know if Виктор Ан is all letters. Tim Berners-Lee is not. One principle in computing is to not force your assumptions on your users, particularly regarding how they identify themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work instead. It can still be simpler and written better, though.

```
    //create a new array with the number of possible ascii characters
    int[] chars = new int[256];

    //loop through the length of first name
    for(int i = 0; i<fnl; i++) 
    {
        //Make lower case and save the char at index i and c
        char c = firstname.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        //cast the saved char as a number and increment that position in the array
        chars[(int) c]++;
    }

    //repeat for last name
    for(int i = 0; i<lnl; i++) 
    {
        char d = lastname.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        chars[(int) d]++;
    }

    //only want to print alphabetical letters a-z
    for(char e = 'a'; e <= 'z'; e++) 
    {
        //if the letter occurs 0 times, we start the loop at the next one
        if (chars[(int) e]==0)
            continue;
        else
            System.out.println("There are "+chars[(int) e]+" "+e+"'s in the String.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a 26 element array to represent the counts:

```
int[] letterCounts = new int(26);
```

You then loop through the letters in the names, something like

```
for (char ch: (firstname+lastname).toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
}
```

In the body of the loop, convert the char, `ch` to an int, and subttract 97, which is the ascii code for `a`:

```
    int c = ((int)ch)-97;
```

This uses the fact that a char really is just an int under the covers -- the `(int)` bit 'casts' the char `ch` to be an `int`. Then use this to address the array:

```
letterCounts[c] = letterCounts + 1;
```

After the loop, you should loop again, this time to print out the array contents and the associated letters, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  System.out.print(((char)i+97));
  System.out.printLn(" " + letterCounts[i]);
}
```

Here we're using a cast again, but this time we're casting an int `i + 97` back to a char so that it can be printed. We've added 97 because when `i` is 0, adding 97 to it makes it 97, and when this is a char it's the letter `a`.

Comment: That looks like what he wanted us to do but again he doesn't really teach. He just says go. Thanks however.

Comment: Learning is an active thing -- you've done the right thing by giving it a go and coming here when you're stuck. Teaching is difficult because it's poorly understood, so you should give your 'teacher' a break, most of them are like that, but they're just doing their best in a poorly understood field.

Comment: Also, we have not learned how to use letterCounts or chararry

Comment: Also, I've been careful here not to help too much, you'll still have to understand what I've written and put the pieces together yourself.

Comment: BTW: i only helped because you'd made an effort to do this yourself and you were struggling. It's your effort that made you worth helping. Most people seeking help with their homework on this site get told to go away.

Comment: `int index = ch - 'a';` would be a bit more readable here, avoiding the magic number.

Comment: Yeah, I attempt each one to the best of my ability. I got what I wanted but I knew there was a way to make it way more compact and simpler to use. Thanks once again

Comment: NP -- if the answer works for you, share the love and hit the tick, thanks.

Comment: @MickMnemonic ty, you're right, but it might confuse the hell out of the student :)